# Your wheels are not turned

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "your wheels are not turned" mean in "[If your brakes fail, and your wheels are not turned, carefully use your park brake to slow your vehicle](https://www.alberta.ca/vehicle-mechanical-problems.aspx)"? Does it mean the wheels are not rotating or revolving? But in that case the car has stopped, which doesn't make sense in this context. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP seems to know the meaning of "turned" and is only confused about the directions in which a car's tires can turn, which isn't an issue of the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that if the wheels are facing forward, that is not angled off to one side or the other.

Comment: I don't even know why I got

Comment: I don't know why I got a -1 for asking something I truly didn't understand, but thank you so much for your answer!